# Load not loading anything from HTML file

Tags: jquery, load

I have an image ( `id="plantilla1"`) and this makes to apear an html into a div (`id="contenidor_plantilla"`). So when I click on the image `plantilla1.html` may be loaded into div with `id="contenidor_plantilla"`.

What's the problem?? it doesn't do anything !!

```
<a href="#" id="plantilla1"><img class="plantilles" src="imatges/plantilles/plantilla1.gif"></a>

<div id="contenidor_plantilla">hola</div>
```

this is the Jquery code :

```
/****************************    TEMPLATE MAKER      ****************/
$(function () {
    $("#plantilla1").click(function () {
        $("#contenidor_plantilla").load('plantilla1.html');
        alert();
    });
});
```

Comment: are the files in the same path ? what does the JavaScript console say ? have you used a debugger to check ? perhaps [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/) ? any errors at all ? have you the included jQuery library ?

Comment: Hi, 
 yes plantilla.html is in the same folder than scripts.js. The function is in scripts.js

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not including your jQuery before this script.Add a jquery plugin at top of this script:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'>
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
      $("#plantilla1").click(function () {
        $("#contenidor_plantilla").load('plantilla1.html');
        alert();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Use it in this order. *`and debug the path of your file which you are trying to load`.*